# site scraping: drop down controls and search button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Imagine a web site, where there are 2 drop down controls like min age and max age. After I choose min age and max age, I would like to hit the search button. How do I get the search results into an output stream and then I could navigate the DOM HTML. I already know how to naviate through dom html via htmlagilitypack. I just do not know how to invoke the drop down make selections and invoke search button. I want to do all this from console application. Is it even possible? I am using C# visual studio 2010.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the html looks like this:

```
<form action="someurl">
    <select name="SomeOption">
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val2">val2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And you want to submit the form with "val1", then you need to execute an HTTP POST operation to "someurl" including the argument SomeOption=val1.  That is essentially what the browser is doing.  Of course the form you are trying to simulate will be a bit more complicated.

Is that what you were asking?

BTW, if you want to see exactly what is going on when the browser submits the form, check out [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), an excellent tool made by a colleague at Microsoft.